# Are Voronoi diagrams used in kNN algo implementations?

Tags: classification, data-visualization, k-nearest-neighbour

It is well-known that Voronoi diagrams are a way to set/describe the kNN solution given the training points.

Are they used in **practical kNN implementations**? I mean, does anyone actually compute Voronoi diagrams to **make predictions**?

upd: I know there are things like KD-trees, R-trees, etc. I'm asking about Voronoi diagrams only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may not be serious implementations doing so. The reason is that the computational complexity for Voronoi diagrams is quite high (around O(n^(k/2))). So it is hard to use it in high-dimensional space. Actually, it would be very hard to compute the diagram even for 8 dimensions.